# How to parse time into DateTimeOffset in a specific time zone?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core

Given the `11:00 PM`, and knowing that the server is running using UTC time, I need to take that time parse it into a DateTimeOffset from a specific TimeZone.

For example if the docker container's time running the server is 2:00 AM 6/3/2022, I need to be able to check if current date time now in 'Eastern Standard Time' zone, is past `6/2/2022 11:00 PM` or before.

To get localized DateTime now I have the following code which works as expected:

```
TimeZoneInfo tzInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
DateTime nowLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now, tzInfo);
DateTimeOffset targetDateTimeOffset =
                new DateTimeOffset(nowLocalTime,
                tzInfo.GetUtcOffset
                (
                    DateTime.SpecifyKind(nowLocalTime, DateTimeKind.Local)
                ));
```

I thought I had it figured out for parsing the time into DateTime and then getting the specific DateTimeOffset object, until it hit past midnight on the server. Since the server's time is now `12:01 AM 6/3/2022` when I run the following code:

```
string timeOfDay = "11:00 AM";
TimeZoneInfo tzInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
DateTime.TryParse(timeOfDay, out DateTime dateTime);
DateTimeOffset targetDateTimeOffset =
                new DateTimeOffset
                (
                    dateTime,
                    tzInfo.GetUtcOffset
                    (
                       DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, 
                       DateTimeKind.Local)
                    )
                );
```

This now returns `6/3/2022 11:00PM`. This makes sense but I need to get DateTimeOffset parsed into the specified TimeZone. Because right now in 'Eastern Standard Time' zone it is 6/2/2022 not 6/3/2022. So basically I need to take `11:00 PM` parse it into `DateTimeOffset` of the provided TimeZone, is that possible?

Comment: `DateTime` barely "works" for UTC & machine local timezones. It's completely broken for everything else and really should be deprecated. Don't use it at all. You want `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, ...`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman what on earth are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The .net `DateTime` type was designed before the age of cloud computing. Where you only had to worry about the machine's `.Local` time or `.Utc`. IMHO `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` should be marked `[Obsolete]` and any API behaviour which relies on it should instead throw an exception.

`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo)` is a particularly strange function. If you pass a `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, or a `TimeZoneInfo` other than `TimeZoneInfo.Local` or `TimeZoneInfo.Utc`, the result is essentially unusable.

IMHO you're better off pushing the problem of parsing and displaying date / time values to the client. Force the client to parse any date time strings in their local timezone. Then either use UTC everywhere, or use `DateTimeOffset` to store the timezone explicitly.

It's easy enough to get the current time in a specific timezone;

```cs
TimeZoneInfo tzInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
DateTimeOffset tzLocalTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, tzInfo);
```

Unfortunately while you can parse a string and `.AssumeLocal` or `.AssumeUniversal`, anything else is barely supported or documented. While you can provide a `CultureInfo` for parsing non-gregorian calendars, there's no `DateTimeOffset.Parse` which takes a default `TimeZoneInfo` parameter. The closest I've found is to check if the string contains an offset, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30739163/4139809).

```cs
static DateTimeOffset ParseAsDateTimeOffset(string s, TimeZoneInfo defaultTimeZone, CultureInfo culture = null)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(s, @"(Z|[+-]\d{2}:\d{2})$"))
        return DateTimeOffset.Parse(s, culture ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var dt = DateTime.Parse(s, culture ?? CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return new DateTimeOffset(dt, defaultTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(dt));
}
```

While this works for most of the year, I'm not certain if it works properly for time values around DST adjustments. But without an explicit offset, those values are going to be wrong anyway.

Comment: Interesting. What do you think of doing something like this.
1. Grab `var localizedNow = DateTime.Now` Localized
2. Convert `11:00 PM` into TimeSpan
3. `localizedNow.Date.AddTicks(timeSpan.Ticks)`
Would this kind of work? You are getting the correct DateTime value for the TimeZone and then you are creating a new DateTime by adding number of Ticks from the time span?